# Get file size in KB/MB/GB in windows batch file

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch-file

I have a Windows (Windows 7/2008 R2) batch file which takes daily backup of file.(Oracle dump export file e.g dump-2016-10-17.DMP)

I want to add the FILE size (in a variable) which should be in KB/MB/GB according to the size, or at least it should get file size in MB. 
CODE:

```
@echo off
SET DONE=0
SET Bytes=%~z1
SET KB=%Bytes:~0,-3%
SET MB=%Bytes:~0,-6%
SET GB=%Bytes:~0,-9%
SET TB=%Bytes:~0,-12%
rem echo %~f1

IF "%KB%" EQU "" SET DONE=B
IF %DONE% EQU B echo Size is... %Bytes% Bytes
IF %DONE% EQU B GOTO END

IF "%MB%" EQU "" SET DONE=K
IF %DONE% EQU K SET /a KB=(%BYTES%/1024)+1
IF %DONE% EQU K echo Size is... %KB% KB
IF %DONE% EQU K GOTO END

IF "%GB%" EQU "" SET DONE=M
IF %DONE% EQU M SET /a MB=(%BYTES%/1048576)+1
IF %DONE% EQU M echo Size is... %MB% MB
IF %DONE% EQU M GOTO END

IF "%TB%" EQU "" SET DONE=M
IF %DONE% EQU M SET /a MB=%KB%/1049
IF %DONE% EQU M echo Size is... %MB% MB (approx)
IF %DONE% EQU M GOTO END

SET DONE=G
IF %DONE% EQU G SET /a GB=%MB%/1074
IF %DONE% EQU G echo Size is... %GB% GB (approx)
IF %DONE% EQU G GOTO END
:END
```

Comment: Did you consider using a PowerShell script instead of a batch? Otherwise this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199645/how-can-i-check-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-windows-batch-script

Comment: Ok i got this from the internet. but this requires me to enter the file name. how can I add file name inside this code to prevent adding argument at the time of execution. `@echo off
SET DONE=0
SET Bytes=%~z1
SET KB=%Bytes:~0,-3%
SET MB=%Bytes:~0,-6%
SET GB=%Bytes:~0,-9%
SET TB=%Bytes:~0,-12%
echo %~f1

IF "%GB%" EQU "" SET DONE=M
IF %DONE% EQU M SET /a MB=(%BYTES%/1048576)+1
IF %DONE% EQU M echo Size is... %MB% MB
IF %DONE% EQU M GOTO END

:END`

Comment: Edit your initial Question with that code. This garbled thing is unusable in that form. In order to have any idea of how to integrate the filename you'd have to post you actual code and not just a fragment you found that does something else. Best approach would be to have two code blocks, one with your code and one with the code you found and would like to integrate. This is probably still easier in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the original question to add the code. I just want to add static file name in this code. like FNAME=d:\setup.exe so that script process the FNAME,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as an alternative, you can use the output of `robocopy` command to retrieve the required information

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file=d:\somewhere\file.ext"

    for %%z in ("%file%") do for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%%~dpz." "%%~dpz." "%%~nxz" /l /nocopy /is /njh /njs /ndl /nc
    ') do if "%%~dz"=="%%~db" (
        echo "%%~z" : [%%a]
    ) else (
        echo "%%~z" : [%%a%%b] 
    )
```

`robocopy` will be used to only list (`/l`) the information of the file being copied, removing any non needed information from the output (the rest of the switches) and using a `for /f` command to tokenize the output lines and read only the file size

In the case of folders, the same idea can be used, but instead of reading the data from the file list, we can use a recursive *"copy"* and retrieve the data from the job summary

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=%~f1" & if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

    set "size=" & for %%z in ("%folder%") do for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3 delims=: " %%a in ('
        robocopy "%%~fz\." "%%~fz\." /l /nocopy /s /is /njh /nfl /ndl /r:0 /w:0 /xjd /xjf /np
        ^| find ":"
    ') do if not defined size (
        (for /f "delims=0123456789." %%c in ("%%b") do (break)) && (
            set "size=%%a%%b"
        ) || (
            set "size=%%a"
        )
    )

    echo "%folder%" : [%size%]
```

Switches changed to retrive only the job summary, and filtered to only read the line containing the `Bytes` information.

**edited** 2016/10/26 - changed robocopy switches to face permission problems, changed `Byte:` retrieval to `:` line filter plus skip clause just in case there is a locale without the `Bytes:` string, changed storage unit detection.

Comment: How i can use the same batch command to get folder size?

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib, What do you mean with *"folder size"*? Files inside the folder? , files under the folder and any subfolder?, ...?

Comment: example i want to get full size of D:\temp folder. There could be sub directories in it like D:\temp\1 d:\temp\2 

So I want full size of the D:\temp folder.

Comment: result should be single entry like

D:\temp = size = 900M or 5GB

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib, answer updated.

Comment: the code to list overall folder size (including subfolders too) is not displaying any size, in fact the code is not returning any output. just blank

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib, Tested on two different systems with two different locales and working. Anyway I've changed the code to face posible problems with filesystem access restrictions or locale conflicts.

Comment: I have tried the updated code in windows 2008 and win 7 / 64bit. with admin account.
I tried updated code and its returning following result.
D:\zaib>size.bat
"D:\zaib" : [:]

I tried to add folder as well like size.bat d:\folder1 but still same.
with previous code, it was not returning any kind of result just blank.

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib, from your output, in your locale the output of the `robocopy` command has space(s) between the `Bytes` string and the colon, something that is not present in the locales I have access to. I've changed the `for /f %%a`  to include a `delims` clause to use include the colons as delimiters instead of handling them as tokens.

Comment: This last updated Worked Perfectly. Many thanks for your time and efforts. Now i can use this in my batch file of backup that will include dir size as well. Thx :)
Output:
D:\zaib>size.bat
"D:\zaib" : [1.728g]

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to call the batch from within your other batch and have the backupfile be the argument. You'd get the size as a text and could save that in a variable.

To do it "inline" you could use it in a loop like this:

```
for %f in (%backupfile%) do set BYTES=%~zf
```

From a readability perspective the first solution would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support and guidelines.

I finally managed to solved it by downloading the `ls` for windows , and using `ls -lh filename` I am getting the info I required along with other information as well.

**Example:**

```
D:\zaib>D:\tools\ls.exe -lh setup.exe

-rwxr-x--a  1 Administrators   590M Oct  6  2015 setup.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two things.

```
filesize.bat 

@echo off
echo %~z1
```

And then what you're actually trying to size up the value reported here

So in this example I evaluate %z% to copy a file only if it's larger than zero / copy only a non-zero file

```
for /f %i in ('filesize filesize.bat') do set z=%i
if %z% gtr 0 ( copy filesize.bat noodles.bat )
```

Something like getting to %z% allows you to do some truncation math or something but getting the size itself is a bit of a pain.